# В ответ на GET запрос приходит ошибка "Unauthorized"

Tags: javascript, post, get

Запрос отправляю через curl. Необходимо получить данные и вставить в react. При отправке получаю ошибку:

```
{“name”:“Unauthorized”,“message”:“Your request was made with invalid credentials.”,“code”:0,“status”:401}
```

Подскажите, как правильно авторизоваться или что нужно сделать, что бы получить в ответ JSON с данными?

Есть Authorization: Bearer и данные для авторизации такие как email и password.

Comment: Вы делаете запрос get к сферическому коню в вакууме?

Comment: https://gentle-escarpment-19443.herokuapp.com/v1/articles?page=1&updated_after=1410403761

Comment: И сам запрос мы тоже должны угадать?

Comment: У меня есть пример запроса curl -v \
     -X GET \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer V9UBRgfy2aPasdQpcMH0J7X32f5GrVpHsG' \
     https://gentle-escarpment-19443.herokuapp.com/v1/articles?page=1&updated_after=1410403761